# UIImageview and TouchesEnded Event

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Im trying to write a simple program that takes 5 images and allows you to drag them from the bottom of the screen and snap them on to 5 other images on the top in any order you like. I have subclassed the UIImageView with a new class and added the touches began, touches moved and touches ended. Then on my main viewcontroller I place the images and set their class to be the new subclass I created. The movement works great in fact I am `NSLogging` the coordinates in the custom class.

Problem is I'm trying to figure out how to get that `CGpoint` info from the touches end out of the custom class and get it to call a function in my main view controller that has the image objects so i can test whether or not the image is over another image. and move it to be centered on the image its over (snap onto it).

here is the code in my custom class m file. MY view controller is basically empty with a xib file with 10 image views 5 of which are set to this class and 5 are normal image views..

```
#import "MoveImage.h"


CGPoint EndPoint;

@implementation MoveImage


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    startPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    }

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint newPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];

    newPoint.x -= startPoint.x; 
    newPoint.y -= startPoint.y;
    CGRect frm = [self frame];
    frm.origin = newPoint;
    [self setFrame:frm]; 
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *end = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    EndPoint = [end locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"end ponts x : %f y : %f", EndPoint.x, EndPoint.y);

} 

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a **MoveImageDelegate** protocol which your app controller would then implement. This protocol would have methods that your MoveImage class can call to get its information.

In your header file ( if you don't know how to write a protocol )

```
@protocol MoveImageDelegate <TypeOfObjectsThatCanImplementIt> // usually NSObject
// methods
@end
```

then you can declare an instance variable of type id, but still have the compiler recognize that that variable responds to your delegate selectors ( so you can code without those annoying warnings ).
Something like:

```
@interface MoveImage : UIImageView
{
 id <MoveImageDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (assign) id <MoveImageDelegate> delegate;
```

Lastly:

```
@implementation MoveImage

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

And your delegate is complete.

Comment: Also I was just thinking that if there is an easier way to to this by adding the touches begin, moved and ended events into my main view controller that would be fine. Just not sure what the best way to do this is. Perhaps creating a custom sub class of uiimage view is not the way to go?

Comment: The UIView is in the responder chain, this means that it will receive the touchesBegan etc. events, your view controller will not. Best would be to tell your view what locations it can "stick" to and then implement that in your touchesBegan etc. methods